# Test Fails from SonarRunner test task but not from project test task in multi project

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have a multi project setup where test task for the sub project builds successfully without any issues but fails when trying to run sonarrunner task. I have test compile dependencies for that subproject on other sub projects. How to tell sonarrunner to include the subprojects in compile time for tests ? I am using gradle as the build system.

```
Project  Structure: 
  Root: 
       Project A
            - Class A
       Project  B
           src
           - Class B
           test
           - TestClass B ( imports Class A )
```

Example:

```
    Sonarrunner task execution 
    :sonarRunner

Execution failed for task ':projectB:test'.
```

Indvidual execution

```
 :projectB:test

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: There's currently not enough to go on here. You're analyzing with sonar-runner, which implies that you're not building with Maven...? 
Also, can you give more information on the analysis error?

Comment: I have added few more details to the question. I am using Gradle build system and my main question is when sonar runs the test task does it include the testcompile dependencies specified in the gradle build file ?  Also can you please explain me what you mean by anaysis error.

Comment: Perhaps the key phrase is this, "when sonar runs the test task" because SonarQube analysis does not execute tests. Those should be executed in advance and the resulting reports fed into the analysis.